# Remove delimiter ↵ when reading text in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, delimiter

I use:

```
file_name='file_name.txt';
fid=fopen(file_name);
line=fgets(fid);
```

How can I remove an enter sign, ↵ , that I sometimes get in line?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fgetl(fid)` instead of `fgets(fid)`.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as an "enter sign", but there are newline characters (depending on the platform: [LF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), [CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), or CR+LF).

You can read the contents of a line without the trailing newline characters e.g. using [fgetl](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html).